# Looking for Azure Java Library sample for pushing AzureKeyvault Certificate in VM

Tags: java, azure, azure-keyvault

I use Java Azure API library to create a VM. I want to be able to install a certificate from AzureKeyVault.

I see Add-AzureRmVMSecret powershell which is used to set the secret , that has certificate URL. I am not able to figure out exact steps for it using Java SDK.

I am creating a VM from Azure MarketPlace.
Any help/pointers appreciated

Comment: Is this what you want?https://github.com/Azure-Samples/key-vault-java-certificate-authentication/

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/key-vault-java-certificate-authentication/blob/master/azurekeyVaultPollSample/src/main/java/com/microsoft/JavaKeyVaultAuthenticator.java) you can find the code sample to read .pfx file from Azure key vault , but you also can do the complete process using ARM and powershell.

here are the steps for doing it

- You need a certificate in .PFX format (See Note 1)
- Create a Key Vault (either using template, or use the simple script below)
- Make sure you have turned on the EnabledForDeployment switch
- Upload the certificate as a secret (see the sample script)
- Now grab the template, provide all the parameter values and then deploy the template

here is the script, that creates a key vault, and then stores a certificate stored in the .pfx file in a local directory, to the Key Vault as a secret.

```
$vaultName = "contosovault"
$resourceGroup = "contosovaultrg"
$location = "eastus"
$secretName = "servicecert"
$certPassword = "abcd1234"
$fileName = "certforvm.pfx"
# =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
$fileContentBytes = Get-Content $fileName -Encoding Byte
$fileContentEncoded = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($fileContentBytes)

$jsonObject = @"
{
  "data": "$fileContentEncoded",
  "dataType" :"pfx",
  "password": "$certPassword"
}
"@

$jsonObjectBytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($jsonObject)
$jsonEncoded = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($jsonObjectBytes)

New-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name $resourceGroup -Location $location
New-AzureRmKeyVault -VaultName $vaultName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -Location $location -sku standard -EnabledForDeployment

$secret = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $jsonEncoded -AsPlainText –Force
Set-AzureKeyVaultSecret -VaultName "contosovault" -Name "servicecert" -SecretValue $secret
```

The first part of the script reads the .pfx file and then stores it as a JSON object with the file content base64 encoded. Then the JSON object is also base64 encoded.

Next it creates a new resource group and then create a key vault. Note the last parameter to the New-AzureKeyVault command, '-EnabledForDeployment', which grants access to Azure (Microsoft.Compute resource provider, if you want to be very specific) to read secrets from the Key Vault for deployments.

The last command simply stores the base64 encoded JSON object in the the Key Vault as a secret.

But this time, the VMs are already running. Hence we need to push the certificates into existing VMs too. First you need to get a new certificate, store it in the key vault (as shown above). You'll notice in the $certUrl below, that it still uses the same secret name, but since this is a new version, the version ID has changed. When we update an existing secret Key Vault will automatically create a new version. You need to grab this new secret version. Then use the 'Add-AzureVMSecret' cmdlet to push the certificate into an existing VM, and finally run Update-AzureVM command so the change takes effect; see the code snippet example below. If new VMs are also going to be created later that need this certificate, you'll also need to update your template with this new secret URI.

```
$subId = (Get-AzureRmContext).Subscription.SubscriptionId
$vm = Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName contosovaultrg -Name contosovm
$SourceVaultId = (Get-AzureRmKeyVault -VaultName contosovault).ResourceId
$certStore = "My";
$certUrl = (Get-AzureKeyVaultSecret -VaultName contosovault -Name servicecert).Id;
$vm = Add-AzureRmVMSecret -VM $vm -SourceVaultId $SourceVaultId -CertificateStore $certStore -CertificateUrl $certUrl;
Update-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName contosovaultrg -VM $vm
```

For added security you can change the attribute for old secret to 'Disabled' so that even if an old template tries to create a VM with this old version of certificate, it will. Here's how you set a specific secret version disabled:

```
Set-AzureKeyVaultSecretAttribute -VaultName contosovault -Name servicecert -Version e3391a126b65414f93f6f9806743a1f7 -Enable 0
```

Also , you can find the template [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/templates/201-vm-push-certificate-windows/).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Mohit, but I am looking for Java SDK sample not Powershell